# Vuetify dialog is not opening on mounted event emit vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am redirecting the user to another page on a button click. and on that page I am sending an event to open dialog. which is working properly, for sending the event and setting the value to true for dialog but it is not showing up yet.

this is the button on which I am sending the event

```
                      <v-btn
                        text
                        small
                        @click.stop="
                          $root.$emit('toggleTransferModal')
                          goToTrasnferModal(camera.id)
                        "
                        >Transfer Camera</v-btn
                      >
```

and on transfer page. on mounted.

```
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on("toggleTransferModal", () => {
      console.log("here")
      console.log(this.dialog)
      this.dialog = !this.dialog
      console.log(!this.dialog)
    })
  },
```

this is how I am getting that event. now its setting the value fo dialog properly but the dialog is not showing up yet.

this dialog code

```
            <template>
              <v-btn
                v-if="owner.email === user_email"
                class="transfer-link caption"
                text
                @click.native.prevent
                @click.stop="dialog = true"
              >
                Transfer
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
              <v-card>
```

as there is transfer button above and on click on that, dialog value set to true and it shows up. but with emit and mount event its not working at all. Is there something wrong or I am missing something?

Comment: please provide a codepen like this https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/abOwMPG?editable=true&editors=101

Comment: so in short the issue is, the same thing is not working when it's in `this.$root.$on("toggleTransferModal", () => {`

Comment: why don't you use only `this.$on` and `this.$emit` with referring to `$root`

Comment: I didnt understand? this is working to put a console message but not working for doing the dialog = true. why is it so?

Comment: this.$on didnt work either

Comment: The issue is with mounted or may be due to something else

Comment: it seems work, if you can share some codesandbox code in order to debug

Comment: I'm facing the same problem currently @JunaidFarooq, did you find a solution? (: